# File upload using protractor and javascripts

Tags: angular, automation, protractor, faker

I am trying to upload a file from HDD (File is available in the Automation framework folder) to the application under test. Every time when I run the script, the application will accept the file having unique name.

How can I chnage the filename every time before uploading the file through automation.

Ex: File name say : filename.csv
I want to change name of the file as below through automation before uploading it.

filename_001.csv
filename_002.csv
filename_003.csv  etc

Comment: do you know how to upload one file?

Comment: Yes... I am able to upload one file.